# Some long and good prerequisite textbooks to the graduate probability textbook by shiryaev and boas?

Tags: probability, soft-question, book-recommendation

Some long and good prerequisite textbooks to the graduate probability textbook by shiryaev and boas?

It seems that it have a big gap between this graduate textbooks and the easier ones.

Comment: Are  you familiar with measure and integration?

Comment: @ncmathsadist - nope

Comment: That is the essential tool.  I am a big fan of Bartle's Elements of Integration. It does a nice, clean job on abstract measure theory.  Once you understand that, you have the tools in place to understand probability at a high level.